# special characters inserted while joining two arrays horizontally separated by comma in Matlab using horzcat

Tags: matlab

I am generating time stamps for 10 days in the format of yyyymmddHHMMSS for each second which means there are 10*24*60*60 timestamp values. Similarly, I am generating 10*24*60*60 Heart rate values which are uniformly distributed between 50 and 70. Both streams(arrays) are generated fine and then I want to join these arrays separated by a comma in which I am getting some issues as special characters are shown in Joined array. The final step is to save this joined matrix to file which will serve as input for my simulation.

So basically file should contain 10*24*60*60 data values in format `yyyymmddHHMMSS,HeartRate`
An example would be `20170102114512,58'. The code I used for generating timestamps and heart rate is

```
    clear all
    close all
    clc

    startDate = datetime(2017,1,1,12,0,1);
    endDate   = datetime(2017,1,2,12,0,0);
    days = 1;
    numberOfSeconds = 60*60*24*days

    data = startDate:seconds(1):endDate ;
    timestamps = datestr(data,'yyyymmddHHMMSS');
    number1 = size(timestamps, 1);


    %   generating heart rates 
    heart_rate = 50 +(70-50) * rand (numberOfSeconds,1);
    intHeartRate = int64(heart_rate);

    number2 = size(intHeartRate, 1);
    % hist(heart_rate)

    % joining time and sensor data
    joined = horzcat( timestamps,intHeartRate)

    dlmwrite('/Users/amar/Desktop/data/heart.txt', joined);
```

I have now two Issues

1. output is generated as below in terminal and it has special characters at end of each value

[image]

1. writing joined matrix into File using `dlmwrite` adds an extra comma to all the values, but I want to output to be written in file as `yyyymmddHHMMSS, HeartRate` format

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the esteem advice of @Jim, I found out that the issue was int and string, so I converted both arrays to a string using `num2str` and then used `strcat` to concatenate two strings. In order to write *joined array* to file I used  `dlmwrite` with delimiter `''`

Code is working like charm

```
clear all
close all
clc

startDate = datetime(2017,1,1,12,0,1);
endDate   = datetime(2017,1,2,12,0,0);
days = 1;
numberOfSeconds = 60*60*24*days

 data = startDate:seconds(1):endDate ;
 timestamps = datestr(data,'yyyymmddHHMMSS');
 number1 = size(timestamps, 1);


 %   generating heart rates 
heart_rate = 50 +(70-50) * rand (numberOfSeconds,1);
intHeartRate = int64(heart_rate);

number2 = size(intHeartRate, 1);
% hist(heart_rate)

% joining time and sensor data
  joinedStream = strcat(num2str(timestamps),{','},num2str(intHeartRate))

 dlmwrite('/Users/amar/Desktop/geenrated/heart.txt', joinedStream,'delimiter','');
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert int HeartRate to a string then it should work.
Join = hortcat(dates,num2str(intHeartRate))

Comment: Thanks a lot. it worked but contents of the file are all separated by a comma example 2,0,1,7,0,1,0,1,1,2,0,6,3,2,6,7

Comment: That's bc you are using dlmwrite, do something like this fid=fopen('file.txt');fwrite(fid,join);fclose(fid)..if this is a problem turn your2d array into 1 big string by appending \n to end of each row before calling fwrite